# Regex: capturing all text between multiple curly braces and anything following the last curly brace

Tags: python, regex

I have text lines such as follows:

```
() \\span{figurato} di \\span{qualcuno} scream loudly
```

from which I need to capture the annotations "*figurato*", "*qualcuno*" and also the "*scream loudly*" string.
In other words I need to capture **each term comprised in curly braces** (called annotations, in variable number from 1 to N) but **also one string with whatever follows the last closing curly braces**.

I have the regex that works well with the first task:

```
{(?P<annotation>.+?)}
```

I also have a regex for the second task:

```
[^}]+$
```

The current python code that works is:

```
def _scanGloss(gloss: str) -> dict:
    return {"gloss": re.search(r"[^}]+$", gloss), "annotations": re.findall(r"{(?P<annotation>.+?)}", gloss)}
```

where gloss is the input line but I'm not succeeding to find a way to do all of this in just one regex. Is it possible?

As a side issue with the second pattern I'm not able to use the parenthesis to define a capture group, but this is less important.

Thank you

Comment: why don't you OR your 2 regexes to get 1?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but using OR how would I know which is which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation.

- We find `\\span{`
- First named group **annotation** `(?P<annotation>[^}]+)` (any character except `}`)
- Skip spaces `\s+`
- Second named group **gloss** `(?P<gloss>(?:\s*[\w]+)*)` (here we are looking for spaces plus words) no space at the end

```
import re

str='\\span{figurato} di \\span{qualcuno} scream loudly'

regex=re.compile(r"\\span{(?P<annotation>[^}]+)}\s+(?P<gloss>(?:\s*[\w]+)*)")

[m.groupdict() for m in regex.finditer(str)]
```

output

```
[ {'annotation': 'figurato', 'gloss': 'di'}, 
{'annotation': 'qualcuno', 'gloss': 'scream loudly'} ]
```